# Monitoring API support in Azure

Tags: java, rest, azure

I want to get the Basic Metrics of a VM in Azure. Basic Metrics would include CPU utilization, Disk Read/Write, Network In/Out.

I looked at [Azure Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt420159.aspx) to see if there's REST API support for accessing the Metrics, but there isn't. Also, Insights REST API only returns Metric Definitions and not the actual metrics. I understand there is a .NET Monitoring API that might provide the data I need, but my application requires a REST API or at the very least a java based solution.

Is there a way of obtaining the metrics using REST APIs?

Answer (score 0):

You could access raw metric data with [Microsoft Azure Insights Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Insights) which includes a unified API to retrieve monitoring metrics and operational events for all of the Azure resources that are available in Azure Resource Manager. And you can refer to [MSDN Library - Microsoft.Azure.Insights](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn802153.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Not sure what unified API you're referring to, but nuGet, AFAIK, is .NET based.  
NuGet is the package manager for the Microsoft development platform including .NET

Answer (score 0):

According to the article [Microsoft Azure Virtual Machine Monitoring with Azure Diagnostics Extension](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-virtual-machine-monitoring-with-wad-extension/), the Azure VM metrics data will be stored in the Azure Table Storage with the same storage account for the VM.

So I think you can try to get the basic metrics data via querying the Azure Table Storgae.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That is the approach I'm going to take now. I'm able to get the Metric Definitions using the instructions mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn931939.aspx). The Metrics Definition does contain information like the tableEndpoint, tableName, sasToken etc. I'm not sure how to use this information to obtain the metric data.

Comment: @prashant You can get the storage account from the `tableEndpoint` and other information used by querying table from the `tableInfo`. Please see the article [How to use Table storage from Java](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-java-how-to-use-table-storage/#how-to-retrieve-all-entities-in-a-partition) to retrieve the data.

Comment: I tried using the same article to get the data. I can list the tables using the `tableClient.listTables()` method. But, I have no clue on what the Entity will look like, more specifically the WADMetricsPT1MP10DV2S20160415 entity,  and hence, I'm not able to make a TableQuery. I tried using the generic `TableQuery<TableEntity>` but that leads to an IllegalArgumentException "Class type must contain contain a nullary constructor.".

Any idea, where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Never mind, I was successful in getting the metric data from the table.

With one simple change of using the DynamicTableEntity instead of TableEntity, I was able to get the data. Thanks for your help Peter!